# Appium: can I do validations in offline mode in appium?

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I am newcomer to the Appium world. I have a ios native app which has offline features like I can go offline & do some actions like adding a bookmark. So I need to do some actions after going offline, can I do this using appium? How can I go offline and do some actions in the native app then come online using the same session/instance and then do some more actions on the app ?

Comment: On the application UI end this shall be done disabling the mobile data and then enabling it back, isn't it?

Comment: Does your native app require Data network ? You can toggle Mobile Data network using Appium.

Answer (score 1):

Use this, this will turn on airplane mode and turn off network on your device.

```
// set airplane mode
driver.setNetworkConnection(1);
```